# Can I handle/intercept json file while navigating a url with WebView2?

Tags: c#, .net-4.8, webview2

I navigate a url. That url also fetches a json file. Can I get it?

webView_NavigationCompleted() only fired when given url done. In short I cannot read any fetched resource like css, js, image and including json code.

I want to filter what webview2 fetches and if url matches i intercept that retrive.

Is there any way to retrive json data during navigation or which is already browsed/fetched? Or can I access webview2 cache?

Answer (score 1):

The [WebView2 Navigation events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/navigation-events) which include `CoreWebView2.NavigationCompleted` as you note only apply to document level navigations. For resources referenced by HTML documents like CSS, or JavaScript resources, you can use [`CoreWebView2.WebResourceResponseReceived`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.webresourceresponsereceived?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1264.42).

There is [some WebView2 sample code using `WebResourceResponseReceived`](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/blob/da3d0b85ea7d97c5b2d68d4ee36bb068e66a6e1d/SampleApps/WebView2WpfBrowser/MainWindow.xaml.cs):

```cs
// During initialization
                window.webView.CoreWebView2.WebResourceResponseReceived += window.CoreWebView2_WebResourceResponseReceived;

// The event handler
        async void CoreWebView2_WebResourceResponseReceived(object sender, CoreWebView2WebResourceResponseReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // <WebResourceResponseReceived>
            ShowNextWebResponse = false;

            CoreWebView2WebResourceRequest request = e.Request;
            CoreWebView2WebResourceResponseView response = e.Response;

            string caption = "Web Resource Response Received";
            // Start with capacity 64 for minimum message size
            StringBuilder messageBuilder = new StringBuilder(64);
            string HttpMessageContentToString(System.IO.Stream content) => content == null ? "[null]" : "[data]";
            void AppendHeaders(IEnumerable headers)
            {
                foreach (var header in headers)
                {
                    messageBuilder.AppendLine($"  {header}");
                }
            }

            // Request
            messageBuilder.AppendLine("Request");
            messageBuilder.AppendLine($"URI: {request.Uri}");
            messageBuilder.AppendLine($"Method: {request.Method}");
            messageBuilder.AppendLine("Headers:");
            AppendHeaders(request.Headers);
            messageBuilder.AppendLine($"Content: {HttpMessageContentToString(request.Content)}");
            messageBuilder.AppendLine();

            // Response
            messageBuilder.AppendLine("Response");
            messageBuilder.AppendLine($"Status: {response.StatusCode}");
            messageBuilder.AppendLine($"Reason: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
            messageBuilder.AppendLine("Headers:");
            AppendHeaders(response.Headers);
            try
            {
                Stream content = await response.GetContentAsync();
                messageBuilder.AppendLine($"Content: {HttpMessageContentToString(content)}");
            }
            catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
            {
                messageBuilder.AppendLine($"Content: [failed to load]");
            }

            MessageBox.Show(messageBuilder.ToString(), caption);
            // </WebResourceResponseReceived>
        }
```